# Short way of writing JFrame settings

Tags: java, swing, optimization, syntax

I'm creating a GUI and have this code:

```
frame.add(container);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocation(200, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Is there a shorter way to write this? I'm mostly asking out of curiosity as I'm always trying to learn new things.

I think I've come across something like this, but I can't get it to work in my application.

```
frame.add(container).setLocation(200,200).pack().setVisible();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override JFrame for this. But i dont se a benefit from what you want to do.

```
public MyFrame extends JFrame{


  public JFrame add(Container container){
    super.add(container);
    return this;
  }

  public JFrame setLocation(int x, int y){
    super.setLocation(x,y);
    return this;
  }
  //and so on
}
```

And then use it like this.

```
MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
frame.add(somecontainer).setLocation(200,200).....
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand that it's mostly not practical, but nice to know there is a way :)'

Answer (score 2):

You cant. Your first call frame.add()returns nothing(void).So not possible for chained method call. May be create A factory class with methods like `createAndShowFrame(JComponent component)`.